# Additional databse - best practices

Tags: security, database, data

Our system needs to synchronize data with external systems by web services. We want additional database to keep needed data and then be able to access it. I wonder how to resolve issue with database owner and security.

Should I create another AD account for new db and make it owner and use it to access data? 
Maybe there is possibility to use some of the sharepoint service accounts? If it's possible, is it safe to do?

Comment: It looks like you need to use bcs

Comment: I don't need this data to be exposed as lists.

Comment: How is the data being synchronized? What are you doing with the data, do you want to see it in SharePoint?

Comment: External system (integration bus) calls webservice on my side and I process the data. This data will be mostly used for some relations (parent-children) and site creation from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is suggested to use dedicated accounts for each application.

There are pros amd cons in that of course, having dedicated accounts provides more security but adds a bit of maintenance.

You should take a look at [Secure Store](http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/how-to-create-configure-consume-sharepoint-2010-secure-store-in-business-connectivity-services/), it might be exactly what you want - if you don't want to create new AD account.